# Как из объекта получить объекты только с необходимыми ключами и значениями. JS

Tags: javascript, json

К примеру есть объект с объектами:

```
obj: {
  obj1: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  },
  obj2: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  },
  obj3: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  }
}
```

Мне нужно вывести те же объекты, но без некоторых ключей

```
obj: {
  obj1: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
  },
  obj2: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
  },
  obj3: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
  }
}
```

Comment: Все объекты одинаковые (с одними и теми же ключами)? Ключи известны заранее?

Comment: да, ключи известны, но их количество может быть разное

Comment: А те ключи, что требуется отобразить, известны и одинаковы для всех? Или зависят от объекта? Возможно ли упорядочить (изменить позицию, порядок) ключи в объекте?

Comment: Короче, суть такая. В бд будет будет лежать массив,  в некоторых ключах будут большие объекты, и я хочу их отфильтровать и отдать серером только то что нужно, чтоб не грузить память лишний раз. Получается, что да ключи известны. В каком плане зависят от объекта? Порядок не важен

Comment: `В каком плане зависят от объекта?` - У всех объектов одинаковые ключи для отображения?
`Порядок не важен` - может, тогда нужные ключи переместить в начало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов в функциональном стиле:

```js
const obj = {
  obj1: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  },
  obj2: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  },
  obj3: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  }
};
const keysToFilterOut = ['key3'];

const filteredObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([key, value]) => [key, Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(value).filter(
        ([subkey]) => !keysToFilterOut.includes(subkey)
      )
    )]
  )
);

console.log(filteredObj);
```

Или в процедурном стиле:

```js
const obj = {
  obj1: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  },
  obj2: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  },
  obj3: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
  }
};
const keysToFilterOut = ['key3'];

const filteredObj = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  filteredObj[key] = {};
  for (const [subkey, subvalue] of Object.entries(value)) {
    if (!keysToFilterOut.includes(subkey)) {
      filteredObj[key][subkey] = subvalue;
    }
  }
}

console.log(filteredObj);
```